# Update Statement Errors Every Time

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am getting fancy (for me at least) with trying to run this update statement.  It should be pretty straightforward, but I can not overcome this obstacle.  Each time I try to run this, it throws an error of

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

I have triple checked all my field names and they are valid, and I have done the best to my knowledge to overcome this obstacle, but alas I have been defeated.

```
update #holdingdata
set 1e2a3m = (select count(*) 
                 from subtodom.blaize.dbo.sassafras 
                 where employeename in (select ename 
                                       from subtodom.hr.dbo.employees 
                                       where status in ('Active') 
                 and CAST(hiredate As Date) between 'Jan 13 2015 12:00AM' and 'Jan 115 2015 12:00AM') 
where manager = 'Jeff'
```

Comment: You need another ) at the end of the row before the where clause.  Right now you're only closing the select ename.  You need to close the select count(*) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update #holdingdata
set 1e2a3m = (select count(*) 
                 from subtodom.blaize.dbo.sassafras 
                 where employeename in (select ename 
                                       from subtodom.hr.dbo.employees 
                                       where status in ('Active') )
                 and CAST(hiredate As Date) between 'Jan 13 2015 12:00AM' and 'Jan 115 2015 12:00AM') 
where manager = 'Jeff'
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this be easier to read as a join instead of two subqueries (hopefully still producing the same result?)

```
update #holdingdata
set 1e2a3m = (
  select count(*) 
  from subtodom.blaize.dbo.sassafras blaize 
  INNER JOIN subtodom.hr.dbo.employees hr 
    ON( blaize.employeename = hr.ename )
  WHERE hr.status = 'Active' AND
  CAST(blaize.hiredate As Date) between 'Jan 13 2015 12:00AM' 
    and 'Jan 115 2015 12:00AM'
)
WHERE manager = 'Jeff'
```

Perhaps also replace count(*) with count( distinct blaize.employeename )